# Azure Service Bus - Paired Namespace Testing

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am trying to implement service bus paired namespaces in our application but not sure how to test this feature after configuration. Can anybody please help me with this?

I have used the same code to configure paired namespace but there is no mention of testing the configuration -

[Azure service bus paired namespace - simulate failover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270726/azure-service-bus-paired-namespace-simulate-failover)

Comment: Share your workaround/code atleast

Comment: I've added another answer to the question that you referenced.